# Custom driver for keyboard GNU/Linux 4.1.0-rc8 (Fedora)

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, usb-device

I am writing a driver for a Logitech G110 USB keyboard for Kernel 4.1.0-rc8.

My driver is perfectly loadable with insmod (Debugging message prints to `dmesg` that it get's initialized through `module_init`).

`modprobe`shows the module in the list just fine (being it with 0 devices using it)

However, when I plug in the keyboard, it seems that the kernel recognizes the Manufacturer and type, and it loads that specific driver:

```
[ 3611.699275] usb 6-5: new high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[ 3611.815794] usb 6-5: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0607
[ 3611.815803] usb 6-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[ 3611.815807] usb 6-5: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[ 3611.817753] hub 6-5:1.0: USB hub found
[ 3611.818776] hub 6-5:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 3612.086996] usb 6-5.1: new low-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
[ 3612.171428] usb 6-5.1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c22b
[ 3612.171436] usb 6-5.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 3612.171441] usb 6-5.1: Product: G110 G-keys
[ 3612.171445] usb 6-5.1: Manufacturer: LOGITECH
[ 3612.179099] input: LOGITECH G110 G-keys as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb6/6-5/6-5.1/6-5.1:1.0/0003:046D:C22B.0014/input/input32
[ 3612.230502] hid-generic 0003:046D:C22B.0014: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.00 Keypad [LOGITECH G110 G-keys] on usb-0000:00:13.2-5.1/input0
[ 3612.230768] usbhid 6-5.1:1.1: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint
[ 3612.294146] usb 6-5.3: new low-speed USB device number 13 using ehci-pci
[ 3612.377583] usb 6-5.3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c22a
[ 3612.377591] usb 6-5.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 3612.377596] usb 6-5.3: Product: Gaming Keyboard G110
[ 3612.384673] input: Gaming Keyboard G110 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb6/6-5/6-5.3/6-5.3:1.0/0003:046D:C22A.0015/input/input33
[ 3612.435649] hid-generic 0003:046D:C22A.0015: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Gaming Keyboard G110] on usb-0000:00:13.2-5.3/input0
[ 3612.443182] input: Gaming Keyboard G110 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb6/6-5/6-5.3/6-5.3:1.1/0003:046D:C22A.0016/input/input34
[ 3612.494710] hid-generic 0003:046D:C22A.0016: input,hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [Gaming Keyboard G110] on usb-0000:00:13.2-5.3/input1
```

Even though the interface is registered just fine:

`[ 4024.380949] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbkeyboard`

The table is specified as follows:

```
struct usb_device_id custom_usb_table[] = {
        { USB_INTERFACE_INFO(USB_INTERFACE_CLASS_HID,
        USB_INTERFACE_SUBCLASS_BOOT, USB_INTERFACE_PROTOCOL_KEYBOARD)},
        { }
};

MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(usb, custom_usb_table);
```

The driver:

```
static struct usb_driver usb_keyboard_driver = {
        .name = "usbkeyboard",
        .probe = usb_probe,
        .disconnect = usb_disconnect,
        .id_table = custom_usb_table
};
```

the `usb_probe` function:

```
static int usb_probe(struct usb_interface *usb_iface,
        const struct usb_device_id *usb_devid)
{
        printk(KERN_DEBUG "CUSTOM-MODULE: USB device was plugged in!\n");
        return 0;
}
```

and `module_init` triggers:

```
static int initialize(void)
{
        int retVal = 0;

        retVal = usb_register(&usb_keyboard_driver);
        printk(KERN_DEBUG "CUSTOM-MODULE: initialize() called!\n");
        if (retVal)
                printk(KERN_DEBUG "CUSTOM-MODULE: Error %d registering driver!\n", retVal);
        return 0;
}
```

(I know that printk is by far the ugliest way to print this debug information, and that there are a LOT of options that are way better, but that's not the point now).

My questions are:

1. I assume above that the kernel "prefers" the specific Logitech driver over the general keyboard interface one I wrote. Is this correct?
2. Is there a way to tell the kernel to not use the Logitech driver until next reboot, but use the General Interface one?

Comment: Have you tried blacklisting the loaded driver? On second thought, although this would work, you'll lose all USB Devices under the HID category.  See the [Specification](http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/), and the [USB Subsystem Entry](http://www.linux-usb.org/USB-guide/x194.html).  In short, you need to add your driver as a driver in the HID set of drivers.

Comment: I haven't actually. I'm a complete noob when it comes to this stuff but I'm trying to work my way through.
Thanks for the links, I'm reading through them right now and I'll post if I find a solution and understand it !

Comment: Great, make sure to use the "Answer Your own Question" Checkbox, and I applaud your effort, as Driver writing is not where most "noobs" tend to jump in.